# Solving linear equations in Python (not working using linalg.solve)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, algebra

Probably this is a very beginner question. I am new to python and such operation. But would appreciate any help.
I am trying to solve a system of linear equations in Python, using numpy linalg.

x+y+z = 2

2x-6y-z=-1

3x-2z=8

I tried to use linalg.solve() function

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,-6,0],[1,-1,-2]])
b = np.array([2,-1,8])
try:
    x1 = linalg.solve(a,b)
except LinAlgError:
    x1 = linalg.lstsq(a,b)[0]
print(x1)
print(np.dot(a,x1) == b)
```

Here is the output

```
[ 5.38709677  1.06451613 -1.83870968]
[ True  True  True]
```

However, this doesn't work if we put these received values instead x,y,z in equations.

I tried another approach

```
x = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(a), b)
print(x)
print(np.dot(a,x) == b)
```

I received the same output as before:

```
 [ 5.38709677  1.06451613 -1.83870968]
```

This method only worked if we change the places of `b` and `np.linalg.inv(a)`. Now it gives correct output.

```
x = np.dot(b, np.linalg.inv(a))
print(x)
print(np.dot(x,a) == b)
```

It works in equations

```
[ 2.  1. -1.]
```

So, here is the question. 
Could anyone please explain why cannot I get [ 2.  1. -1.] using `linalg.solve`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix `a` describing the left-hand side of the equation is set up the wrong way around;

```
 np.linalg.solve(a.T, b)
```

does what you want to do with the given `a`.

That your second approach does the job boils down to the fact that for any 2-dimensional `ndarray` `a`, and any 1-dimensional `ndarray` `x` for which the shapes match, `np.dot(a, x)` will equal `np.dot(x, a.T)`. This is the case since in the two operations, viewed as matrix multiplications, `x` is treated as a column and row vector respectively, and for any matrix $A$ and any vector $x$, $Ax = (x^TA^T)^T$.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your `a` does not match the equations you wrote at the beginning of your question. You have

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,-6,0],[1,-1,-2]])
```

Which corresponds to:

- x + 2y + 3z
- x - 6y
- x - y - 2z

Which isn't what you put at the top of your question.

Note that the `[True, True, True]` is showing you this. The fact that the dot product produced values matching `b` indicates that it did solve for the `a` and `b` in your code.